# How does EL context resolve UIData 'var' attributes?

Tags: jsf, el

I am trying to create a custom UIData component and I am having troubles with Ajax. The first call works fine, but subsequent calls cannot resolve my UIData 'var' attribute. When trying to debug, I can see that the first ajax call restores my custom UIData and puts the 'var' into the RequestMap. Subsequent calls though do not call again restoreState resulting in an empty 'var' variable.

PS. Apologies for this post not being very SSCCE but it would be very large.

Comment: In other words, the `value` resolved to an empty collection/object?

Comment: exactly. I updated the reason below

Comment: Okay. On a side note, please don't tag questions with specifically JSF 2.2 unless you have evidence that the problem can't be reproduced in older versions. Use the JSF 2.2 tag for stuff specific to JSF 2.2 only. Just mention the exact impl/version directly in the question. E.g. "Mojarra 2.2.1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was not using

```
UIComponentBase.restoreAttachedState(context, values[1]);
UIComponentBase.saveAttachedState(context, getValue());
```

in Save and restore state

```
public Object saveState(FacesContext context)
public void restoreState(FacesContext context, Object state)
```

Another issue was that I didn't reset the rowIndex of the UIData

```
 setRowIndex(-1);
```

in the

```
public boolean visitTree(VisitContext context, VisitCallback callback)
```

This causes the id of the saved state to be adjusted with the index resulting to a key miss in the next restore phase.

Comment: It would be interesting to know the (_url_) in the case that you were trying to follow some tutorial. Also, where did you find this useful answer. Thank you and Regards,

Comment: Unfortunatelly I am not following a tutorial but I am debugging through the code. The key components are UIData & UIComponent (superclasses of the dull HtmlDataTable which is the implementation of h:datatable). Also HtmlTableRenderer and its superclasses are a good source. I haven't made much progress on creating a clean example but I recommend debugging the flow. One good exercise is to try and render the h:datatable without the facets but with your structure e.g. divs. The j2ee tutorial can help you start on the basics [j2ee 6] (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnavt.html)

Comment: Thank you, very helpful to know about that tutorial!

Answer (score 1):

Although my answer might be interesting for some, it didn't answer how UIData 'var' is resolved. The answer is that in each iteration/phase of UIData processing the setRowIndex(int) method is called which sets the 'var' attribute with the data from the dataModel in the request map (See extract below). This is called by the UIData method invokeOnComponent or UIData.visitTree() which is called by FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.locateComponentByClientId() in JSF 1.2 or by various places in JSF2 including state Management Strategies, ViewContextImpl and many others:

See change in this link under -Tree visiting
http://andyschwartz.wordpress.com/2009/07/31/whats-new-in-jsf-2/

Documentation on visitTree:
[http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#visitTree(javax.faces.component.visit.VisitContext, javax.faces.component.visit.VisitCallback)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#visitTree%28javax.faces.component.visit.VisitContext,%20javax.faces.component.visit.VisitCallback%29)

This is the extract from UIData:

```
String var = (String) getStateHelper().get(PropertyKeys.var);
        if (var != null) {
            Map<String, Object> requestMap =
                  getFacesContext().getExternalContext().getRequestMap();
            if (rowIndex == -1) {
                oldVar = requestMap.remove(var);
            } else if (isRowAvailable()) {
                requestMap.put(var, getRowData());
            } else {
                requestMap.remove(var);
                if (null != oldVar) {
                    requestMap.put(var, oldVar);
                    oldVar = null;
                }
            }
```